# Holomorphic function being identically zero

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

I've got this question that I've been trying to prove using no Taylor/Laurent series, no use of Residue theorem, only using the Cauchy's integral formula but have not made any progress on. unfortunately

Let f is holomorphic on $D_1(0)$ and is such that $max_{z \in C_r(0)} |f(z)| \to 0$
as $r \to 1$. Prove that $f$ is identically zero.

I would appreciate any helps.

Comment: Where do you see any problem? Give $z$, you can pick $r$ such that $|\zeta-z|>\frac{1-|z|}2$ and make $f(\zeta)$ arbitrarily small in the Cauchy integral formula

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen could you elaborate more on your comment? I can see how using the $| \zeta - z| > \frac{1-|z|}{2}$ might be helpful but I'm not entirely sure if I might be on the right track or not.